# Working in two jobs at the same time (different countries)

Tags: contracts, part-time

Currently, I'm a data scientist in an NLP company in Spain. I got an appourtunity to start a post-doc in a canadian research institute (in Canada of course ;)).

My team leader in the company would like me to keep working with them as a part time job.

Thus, should I inform my new Post-doc supervisor or keep this "secret" as it's a part-time job and I do it out of the working hours?

Might I have problems in the future if I keep it secret thing?

Comment: Why would you even want to keep it a secret?

Comment: Are part-time jobs illegal in your country, or banned by your company, or the institute?

Comment: @Belal.ghanem are you not allowed to do both jobs? Sounds like something you need to find out before making any decisions.

Comment: @SouravGhosh .. to be honest, I don't know. But it has nothing with my country .. it will something regarding the canadian rules.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul .. because maybe I won't be allowed to continue working with the company + The postdoc is something temporal, so I don't want to lose my job with the company.

Comment: @Belal yes, you need to find that out. I am sure that there are plenty of resources on that in canada, or maybe that asks for a different question whether you are allowed to do that. But until that is clear, this question seems to be premature, as hiding things is a last resort, not go-to.

Comment: When this is about a post-doc position in academia, then this might be more of a topic for https://academia.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most of the time, keeping secrets do more harm than good. Once that secret is revealed, above everything, you lose the trustworthiness.

In this scenario, there's nothing to hide, as the part-time job during an academic course is not usually forbidden, rather the contrary. Check with the research institute about their rules of part-time work

- Most likely you won't find anything that prohibits you from continuing the current work as part-time.
- If for some reason there's a clause prohibiting from doing part time work, you need to make a choice, whether to accept the offer for research work or to keep the job and search for another opportunity which allows you to make a balance between the research work and part-time job.

Overall, you need to be very clear and informed about the dos and don'ts before you sign up for anything. This will save you a lot of trouble at later point of time.